# Issue with pointers to memory allocation

Tags: c++, loops, pointers

Considering the following code block:

```
  Byte* b = (Byte*) var.rawBuffer();
  b += sizeof (Byte) * 9;
  WhateverType* aptr = (WhateverType*) b;
  WhateverType* anotherptr = aptr;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    assert(*anotherptr == aptr[i]);
    anotherptr += sizeof (WhateverType);
  }
```

Why do the assertion fail, sometimes? Is not scanning allocated memory using the `[]` operator with an index on the starting memory address equivalent to increment the pointer address by the size of the data type I am trying to read?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't reading past the end of the buffer? How is `operator==` defined for `WhateverType`? Could you give us a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: `anotherptr += sizeof (WhateverType);` --> should be `anotherptr+=1`. That being said, you still may have alignment issues casting a Byte pointer to a WhateverType.

Comment: Because pointer addition doesn't work this way. Change it last line in the `for` loop to simply `++anotherptr`.

Comment: `sizeof (WhateverType)` is `sizeof (a_pointer)` NOT `sizeof (a_byte)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
anotherptr += sizeof (WhateverType);
```

`anotherptr` is a `WhateverType*` pointer, not a `Byte*` pointer. When you perform arithmetic on a typed pointer, the total byte count is an even multiple of the type that the pointer is declared as.

So, in the line above, you are not telling the compiler to increment the pointer by just `sizeof (WhateverType)` number of bytes only, like you are expecting. You are actually telling it to increment the pointer by `sizeof(WhateverType)` number of elements, or in other words, by `sizeof(WhateverType) * sizeof(WhateverType)` number of bytes.

```
T *pointer = ...;
pointer += N;
```

Is effectively equivalent to the following:

```
pointer = reinterpret_cast<T*>(reinterpret_cast<byte*>(pointer) + (sizeof(T) * N));
```

Even the statement `aptr[i]` works the same way, as the expression `pointer[N]` is just syntax sugar for `*(pointer + N)`.

For what you are attempting, you need to increment your `anotherptr` pointer by `N=1` element, not by `N=sizeof(WhateverType)` number of elements.  So, use this instead:

```
anotherptr += 1;
```

Or simpler:

```
anotherptr++; // or: ++anotherptr;
```

Comment: all good except because of type punning resulting pointer may have different alignment requirements, so that line with `reinterpret_cast` is true only when `T` is Byte-aligned.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie, what do you mean with `T is byte-aligned`? Can you, please, provide some examples?

Comment: @rudicangiotti see [Objects and alignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object) on cppreference.com